# Is there a way to define a type/interface that limits the keys or the extended type/interface?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a classic interface to define routes:

```
interface Routes {
  [key: string]: string | Routes;
}
```

And I like to define sub-interfaces for each modules, for example:

```
interface GeoRoutes extends Routes {
    country: {
        list: string;
    };
}
```

So far so good, but I'd like to prevent `GeoRoutes` objects from having other undefined keys.
For example declaring this, compiles :

```
const apiRoutes: GeoRoutes = {
    foo: 'bar',
    country: {
        list: '/countries',
    },
};
```

but I wish it didn't.

For me the whole point of extending a parent interface is to use it in methods that work on Routes, like for example:

```
function addRoute(routes: Routes) { ... }
```

Comment: Why extend `Routes` if you don't want the index signature ?

Comment: The main idea was to have a parent interface to manipulate routes in generic methods. And also give a kind of template for the definition of routes for each module. But I'm starting to wonder if that was a good idea.

Comment: Seems like you want a *check* on `GeoRoutes` instead of having it extend `Routes`; maybe something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m33p2m) would work for you where you write `interface Foo extends VerifyRoutes<{...}> {}` instead of `interface Foo extends Routes {...}`?  If that seems promising I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, it definitely helps, thank you. Typescript has a powerful type system but I sometimes find the syntax for type definition quite difficult coming from language like Java/Kotlin. I've played with your playground the only thing I'm missing is that I can't find a way to use a `VerifyRoutes` as a method parameter. Let's say I have a method like that :`function addRoute<T extends VerifyRoutes<?>>(routes: T) { ... }` . I'd like it to accept any type extending VerifyRoutes.

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/weBDXN)? If that works for you, could you [edit] the question to make it clear that you also want this to act as a method parameter via an example so that I can put it in my answer?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I have edited the question to add details about why I what to extend a parent interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more like you want to *check* `GeoRoutes` against `Routes` instead of *extending* it.  Sort of like [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) but for types.  My inclination would be to create a helper type called `SatisfiesRoutes<T>` that doesn't alter its type, but will complain if `T` would be an invalid `Routes` type.  Perhaps like this:

```
type SatisfiesRoutes<T extends (ToRoutes<T> extends infer U ? U : never)> = T;

type ToRoutes<T> = T extends object ?
  { [K in keyof T]: string | ToRoutes<T[K]> } : never;
```

The `ToRoutes<T>` type takes a type and turns it into a valid `Routes` my recursively mapping the properties to either `string` or `ToRoutes<>` for the properties.  The idea is that if `T extends ToRoutes<T>` then `T` is a valid `Routes`; otherwise the failure of `T extends ToRoutes<T>` would give error information about what is wrong with `T`.

Note that I would have loved to write `type SatisfiesRoutes<T extends ToRoutes<T>> = T`, but the compiler sees that as illegally circular.  Without support for arbitrary circular constraints as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#51011](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51011) I need to work around it.  By using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) as `ToRoutes<T> extends infer U ? U : never` I delayed the evaluation long enough to avoid circularity detection.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
interface GeoRoutes extends SatisfiesRoutes<{
  country: {
    list: string;
  };
}> { } // okay

interface BadGeoRoutes extends SatisfiesRoutes<{
  country: {
    list: number; // error!
  };
}> { } // Types of property 'list' are incompatible
```

So it allows good types and disallows bad ones.  And because `SatisfiesRoutes` just returns its argument, the `GeoRoutes` type doesn't have an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and thus object literals will undergo [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) as desired:

```
const apiRoutes: GeoRoutes = {
  foo: 'bar', // excess property warning
  country: {
    list: '/countries',
  },
};
```

---

The `T extends ToRoutes<T>` constraint-like behavior for validating/invalidating potential `Routes` types can also be used in place of `Routes` in cases where you don't actually want to worry about index signatures, as shown here:

```
function addRoute<T>(routes: T extends ToRoutes<T> ? T : ToRoutes<T>) { }
addRoute({ z: "abc", y: { x: "def" } }); // okay
addRoute({ z: "abc", y: { x: "def", w: 123 } }); // error!
// -------------------------------> ~
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=false&ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghsAlgZwGaIsgSgewK7CYA8AKlBAB6EB2AJslABQk64HEkB85VEdDiaqggAnKAFUoAfglQAXFGoQAbqICU3ALxQSAbgCwAKCOhIO1vkLJSWnTxr0oOAEYArCAGNg0o1CgBvKABtAGkoQSgAawgQHFQdAF0FZGARQQBzKAAfczYrUlCE7gBfeUUVUQNjQ0FCEVQ4D2gAcQgLdgZKBwZ4JDQMbEtif18oD3xqVJAFEcM-PwAbFGBk1Iyqv2Kq4u5A4qMjWtEGpqgAIThaVvarez5HXpR0TDzh0fG8SZFpgNHF5YU1DwAFtnJUoAB6CHkEQiHAiACEoy2Rh2ASgpShOnAmCc8TAcMgIlAUAA5EsUqSoHARNBBONgWAEIhnAsIAdquNqClqWBEK9kAprgKoNpZn5UDgcApSc4aaSADSQ6GUJrIBgEnBEkkAdxp1Ay7wmUxmfygFJWZIhHy+A0VyIVqKqHKMqE+XkQOGo1NotFeNkYcI6CjIXXuDBYAps0jsIZuHE4anR+0Mlz9Q0YgQAXgoAERwZweXNKn6BCh52gQVC5jEYtRVNOvTNQHNQfOF4tQUtQcttyvVpU6hQARgATABmWvFevKmFwxFGLEAWhXq7X643m9X3AAfovoSQcWSgaDRFSUIocN44OrEOlqAW2VBgDhn0fSSk0tR0qSAHRAA)