# Constraining property names in an interface that uses declaration merging (possibly via extending?)

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I am trying to use a typescript feature called "declaration merging" in order to allow my codebase to "declare" an interface in multiple files, which would then extend those key value pairs in the entire application. As shown below:

```
declare global {
   interface Selectors {
      foo: number
      bar: string
   }
}
```

However I would like to constrain the names the users can define in this interface to adhere to a certain naming pattern, specifically `"select${Capitalize<string>}"`, meaning keys such as `foo` and `bar` would be unacceptable, rather `selectFoo` or `selectBar` would be suitable.

I was thinking of using the `extends` feature to extend a Record with such keys, but the problem is, just because type **A** extends type **B**, does not mean that the same constraints that are applied to **B** is applied to **A** (and it shouldn't).

I am unsure how to achieve this, as I need users to be able to define any keys they want, so long as they adhere to the pattern, yet this has to be a "declaration merging" type of interface.

I've found something similar in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75247016/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-type-interface-that-limits-the-keys-or-the-extended-t) post, however I am not sure how to use that, or even if it is the same kind of issue, i feel like it is not. Mine is more about naming, the type that is related to the property can be any type.

Comment: Anything I could think of to do here would either be illegally circular or cause your desired error to appear somewhere remote from the offending key.  Are you interested in a solution that has the latter issue?

Comment: It is better than nothing for sure, I am currently stuck with defining these things to be "global accessible" for type inferences across files that are not explicitly linked, I am also open to any other idea that would allow the same/similar functionality.

Comment: So, something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7G3GN) will work, but it's not great because that error will probably show up in a different file from where the user does something bad.  I can write up an answer if you want.

Comment: Okay um what sort of DARK MAGIC is happening here, I would really like an explenation

Comment: Heh well I'd be happy to write it up when I get a chance, but only assuming you think it addresses the question well enough.  Is that the case?

Comment: I do not think this will work for my issue, it is better than having nothing but I think I need to look for a different idea and drop this one. Do you perhaps have an idea of where I should look / direct me? I am also not sure if it is clear what I am trying to achieve

Comment: I do think I understand what you're trying to achieve.  As for where to direct you I just don't know; it used to be possible, more or less, with something like `interface Foo extends Record<keyof Foo, ⋯>` but it no longer works and [ms/TS#40315](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40315) is classified as a design limitation.  There are various features which, if implemented, would help, but nothing that's part of the language.

Comment: Hmmmpf, this is a pain point for sure :D Thanks either way, you've been of great help, as always.